# Help Required in Collision Detection Using Box2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

After some sample projects, I have started with my first game in cocos 2d and box 2d where objects fall from a parachute and you kill them using slingshot. Now i'm stuck @ couple of things for a while:

Collision Issue:

1. Using Box 2d i have made collision with objects. However when i add a counter to get a count of my collision i doesn't work. Counter increases even though the percentile is moved out of the screen.Don't know how to get rid of this.
2. I'm trying to get random rotation to my sprites which fall from above, Like a parachute experience. Now all of then rotate @ a same angle.
3. Lastly i need to get rid of the surrounding sprites when collision happens. Ex: When  the percentile collides with a falling object, in a radius of 2.5 cms the other sprites should also disappear.

I Badly need help and suggestions, hence all the 3 questions @ once :-). I have provided the link for my project so that you can look @ the source code. Desperately looking for your help guys!!!

Download Source Code:

http://jumbofiles.com/6fn5mmpnq1q8/Karthik.zip.html

Budding Developer,

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty good tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12

I think that one can solve your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the best tutorial for the particular requirement you have described over here..... 
The link for that is as follows
http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone
The tutorial is of 2 parts and describes the code briefly.. The code of that is described and you can get good amount of help from there.

Answer (score 0):

ques 1 + 3: you need read link which share by Mikael and Marine

ques 2: in cocos2d, if you want get random value, you can use support function (such as: rand(), random(), CCRANDOM_0_1() ....)... i think, you need set rotation value for object. i dont know your problem, you need explain it (link is "File Not Found or Deleted / Disabled due to inactivity or DMCA")